# C++: cannot convert argument 2 from 'int' to 'const Vector &'

Tags: c++

im kinda new to c++ and i just can't figure it out on how to fix the problem

the intelisense error i get is  *no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "Vector"*

here is an snippet of code

```
            Vector vTargetPos = GetEnemyLKP();
        vTargetPos.z = GetFloorZ(vTargetPos);

        if (GetNavigator()->SetRadialGoal(vTargetPos, random->RandomInt(50, 500), 23, 90, 175, m_bLoopClockwise))
        {
            TaskComplete();
            return;
        }
        TaskFail(FAIL_NO_ROUTE);
```

The intelisense error happens on line 4 random.

i have tried to look for ways to fix it but i could'nt find any relatble fixes

Comment: could you please share SetRadialGoal  function declaration  ?

Comment: you mean this: bool    SetRadialGoal( const Vector &destination, const Vector &center, float radius, float arc, float stepDist, bool bClockwise, bool bAirRoute = false );

Comment: what about the declaration of this function RandomInt ?

Comment: Here: virtual int  RandomInt( int iMinVal, int iMaxVal ) = 0;

Comment: try this : 
std::vector<int> vec(random->RandomInt(50, 500));
 if (GetNavigator()->SetRadialGoal(vTargetPos,vec, 23, 90, 175, m_bLoopClockwise))
        {
            TaskComplete();
            return;
        }

Comment: Ok i will try that thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (GetNavigator()->SetRadialGoal(vTargetPos, random->RandomInt(50, 500), 23, 90, 175, m_bLoopClockwise))
```

Random function type is int but second reference of SetRadialGoal function is const Vector&. Compiler can't convert int to Vector because there is no constructor for that. So, you should create a constructor for convert int to Vector or simply change second reference of SetRadialGoal to int.